# How to write a procedure to print a string and a newline character in x86 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to write a some reusable procedures to print strings in x86 assembly:

- `print_str`: prints a 0-terminated string
- `print_nl`: prints a newline character
- `print_strnl`: prints a 0-terminated string, then a newline character

`print_str` works fine, but for some reason, `print_nl` and `print_strnl` both go into an infinite loop.

Here's my code an the output:

```
;
; String handling
;

code segment para public 'CODE'
assume cs:code ds:data ss:stack es:nothing

main proc far
    push    ds
    xor     ax, ax
    push    ax
    mov     ax, data
    mov     ds, ax

    mov     si, offset t_something
    cld
    call    print_nl

    ret
main endp

;
; Print a 0-terminated string
;
; Parameters:
; - SI: the offset of the string
;
print_str proc
print_str_start:
    lodsb
    cmp     al, 0
    je      print_str_end
    mov     ah, 14
    int     10h
    jmp     print_str_start

print_str_end:
    ret
print_str endp

;
; Print a newline character
;
print_nl proc
    mov     si, offset t_newline
    cld
    call    print_str
print_nl endp

;
; Print a 0-terminated string, then a newline character
;
; Parameters:
; - SI: the offset of the string
;
print_strnl proc
    call    print_str
    call    print_nl
print_strnl endp

data segment para public 'DATA'

t_newline     db  13, 10, 0
t_something   db  'SOMETHING', 0

data ends

stack segment para stack
    dw  100 DUP (?)
stack ends

end main
```

Output:

```
SOMETHING
SOMETHING
SOMETHING
SOMETHING
SOMETHING
SOMETHING
SOMETHING
(...) - infinite loop
```

Could you please explain what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `endp` actually adds a `ret` for you. Add it yourself if it doesn't. Alternatively, you can just use `jmp` for the final call instructions, such as:

```
;
; Print a newline character
;
print_nl proc
    mov     si, offset t_newline
    cld
    jmp     print_str
print_nl endp

;
; Print a 0-terminated string, then a newline character
;
; Parameters:
; - SI: the offset of the string
;
print_strnl proc
    call    print_str
    jmp     print_nl
print_strnl endp
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now! BTW, aren't you *that* Jester? (I had an ex-coworker in Hungary who used the same nickname)